# Why is CONCAT_WS Expecting '(', or SELECT?

Tags: sql-server

CONCAT_WS does not seem to be functioning correctly.  It throws a syntax error on the string I put in for the separator argument.

The following will reproduce my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE personnel(
    personnel INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR(20), 
    lastName VARCHAR(20),
    login VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    title varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    initials varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    startDate DATE DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    CONSTRAINT PkPersonnel PRIMARY KEY(personnel),
    CONSTRAINT UqPersonnelFirstNameLastName UNIQUE(firstName, lastName),
    CONSTRAINT UqPersonnelInitials UNIQUE(initials)
);

CREATE TABLE actionRequest(
actionRequest INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
dateOpened DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
whoIsResponsible INT NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(3000) NOT NULL,
isActionCorrective BIT NOT NULL,
rootCause VARCHAR(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
potentialActions VARCHAR(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
actionSelected VARCHAR(1000),
actionAssignedTo INT,
actionCommunicated BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
actionCompleted bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
effectivenessReview VARCHAR(1000),
dateClosed DATE,
CONSTRAINT PkActionRequestActionRequest PRIMARY KEY(actionRequest),
CONSTRAINT FkActionRequestWhoIsResponsible FOREIGN KEY(whoIsResponsible) REFERENCES personnel(personnel),
CONSTRAINT FkActionRequestAssignedTo FOREIGN KEY(actionAssignedTo) REFERENCES personnel(personnel),
CONSTRAINT CkActionRootCauseRequirement CHECK(isActionCorrective = 0 OR NOT(rootCause IS NULL OR rootCause = ''))
);

CREATE TABLE ncw(
    ncw INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    dateFound DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    whoIsResponsible INTEGER NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(3000),
    significanceEvaluation VARCHAR(3000),
    jobsAffected VARCHAR(1000),
    workHalted BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    reportsDelivered VARCHAR(1000),
    remedialAction VARCHAR(1000),
    likelyToRecur BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    actionRequestNumber INTEGER,
    dateClosed DATE,
    CONSTRAINT PkNcwNcw PRIMARY KEY(ncw),
    CONSTRAINT FkNcwWhoIsResponsible FOREIGN KEY(whoIsResponsible) REFERENCES personnel(personnel),
    CONSTRAINT FkNcwActionRequestNumber FOREIGN KEY(actionRequestNumber) REFERENCES actionRequest(actionRequest),
    CONSTRAINT ChkActionRequestNumber CHECK(likelyToRecur=0 OR actionRequestNumber>=1)
);
```

And here is the command I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT 1 order, 'Unresolved Nonconforming Work' category, CONCAT_WS(' | ', ncw, dateFound, concat_ws(' ', whoIsResponsible.firstName, whoIsResponsible.lastName), description) details
FROM ncw JOIN personnel AS whoIsResponsible ON
whoIsResponsible.personnel = ncw.whoIsResponsible
```

All of this is up at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/50d806/2).

When I run it, I get

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

When I enter my command in SSMS, it highlights my separator, ' | ' and when I mouse over it, the screen tip says

> Incorrect syntax near " | ".  Expecting '(', or SELECT.

Why does it not like my separator string?  I tried adding parentheses around the separator, but that didn't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not from `CONCAT_WS`
It's because `order` in the first line `1 order` (it's reserved keyword)

You can use `1 [order]` (I suggest to use as for the alias `1 as [order]`

The list of keywords [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/50d806/15)